# What does the document cap mean in Websolr?

Tags: heroku, websolr

I'm using [the Websolr addon](https://addons.heroku.com/websolr) in Heroku. What does it mean by "250,000 documents"? What number of DB records or size is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick from Websolr here.

In this case, 'documents' would be all the distinct 'things' that you want to search.

A Solr index is comprised of many documents. Each document has many fields. Typically each document is analogous to a row in a table, or an instance of a model for your particular ORM.

Typically, a Solr client for your preferred language will help you integrate that concept into your own application and the tools you have used to create it.

Answer (score 1):

In Solr a document is an indexed 'item'.